# What is this metal piece sticking up on the roof of a 182?

Tags: feature-identification, cessna-182

My CFI and I were stumped as to what the purpose of this metal piece is on the roof of a 182. I couldn't find anything from searching Cessna POHs/docs online... Any ideas? [image: probe]

Here is a close-up: [image: probe_close_up]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be an Outside Air Temperature probe.

Comment: Yep. Definitely not an antenna.

Comment: @JScarry - Do not put a Jack-in-the-box, styrofoam, antennae ball on it. 

Comment: Correct, @DeanF., that goes on the larger antenna to the right in the 1st pic.